# Can I use a custom hook inside of a custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to separate logic in my app and I was wondering If is it possible to call a custom hook inside another custom hook

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just follow the main rules of hooks. Don't call them conditionally, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a custom hook inside another custom one.
I offer to read this article to use it right away. Link: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexey. It was very helpful.